# extract file content using a bash script

Tags: bash

It has been  long time since my last bash script.
I m just trying to extract the content of a file from the the start variable to the stop one.
My source file is night4.info and it contains a list of .jpg files.The structure of this file is similar to:

```
./2014-11-02/18h/00mn/2014-11-02T18-00-00.048000-depth.jpg
./2014-11-02/18h/00mn/2014-11-02T18-00-00.182000-depth.jpg
./2014-11-02/18h/00mn/2014-11-02T18-00-00.316000-depth.jpg
```

This is the code so far :

```
#! /bin/bash
start=$(grep -n $1 night4.info | cut -d : -f 1)  
stop=$(grep -n  $2 night4.info  | cut -d : -f 1)
echo "1" >> list.info
sed -n -e "$start,$stop p" night4.info >> list.info
```

And this is how I m running my script:

```
./script1.sh 2014-11-02T18-00-00.048000 2014-11-03T06-59-59.981000
```

There is no error message and the code  doesn't give the right output.

Comment: What is your source file? and what is that you are trying to extract? Without the actual file, question is pointless

Comment: You can improve this question by trying to isolate the problem. Instead of pasting four lines and stating that it doesn't give the right output, find the smallest piece of code that doesn't do what you expect and show it along with input,  expected output and actual output. See the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for an example of how to turn a bad script into a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Perl one-liner with the range operator:

```
perl -ne "print if /\Q$1\E/../\Q$2\E/" night4.info >> list.info
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? It appears to just print everything

Comment: It is working. But it will be better for me if I can fix my bash script. Thanks.